# $router.push not working in vuejs application

Tags: vuejs3, vuetify.js, vue-router

I have the following vue code: login.vue from https://github.com/themeselection/sneat-vuetify-vuejs-admin-template-free

```
<script setup lang="ts">
import AuthProvider from '@/views/pages/authentication/AuthProvider.vue'
import logo from '@images/logo.svg?raw'

const form = ref({
  email: '',
  password: '',
  remember: false,
  message:''
});


function login(){
// Make a POST request to the CodeIgniter API endpoint using fetch
fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/validateCredentials', {
                        method: 'POST',
                        headers: {
                            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                        },
                        body: JSON.stringify({
                            username: form.value.email,
                            password: form.value.password
                        })
                    })
                    .then(response => response.json())
                    .then(data => {
                        if (data.status === 'success') {
                            form.value.message = 'Login successful!';
                            $router.push('dashboard');
                        } else {
                            form.value.message = data.message;
                        }
                    })
                    .catch(error => {
                        form.value.message = 'An error occurred. Please try again later.';
                    });

}


const isPasswordVisible = ref(false)
</script>

<template>
  <div class="auth-wrapper d-flex align-center justify-center pa-4">
    <VCard
      class="auth-card pa-4 pt-7"
      max-width="448"
    >
      <VCardItem class="justify-center">
        <template #prepend>
          <div class="d-flex">
            <div
              class="d-flex text-primary"
              v-html="logo"
            />
          </div>
        </template>

        <VCardTitle class="text-2xl font-weight-bold">
          sneat
        </VCardTitle>
      </VCardItem>

      <VCardText class="pt-2">
        <h5 class="text-h5 mb-1">
          Welcome to sneat! 
        </h5>
        <p class="mb-0">
          Please sign-in to your account and start the adventure
        </p>
      </VCardText>

      <VCardText>
        <!--<VForm @submit.prevent="$router.push('/')">-->
        <VForm @submit.prevent="login">
          <VRow>
          <div v-if="form.message" class="danger">
          {{form.message}}
          </div>
            <!-- email -->
            <VCol cols="12">
              <VTextField
                v-model="form.email"
                autofocus
                placeholder="johndoe@email.com"
                label="Email"
                type="email"
              />
            </VCol>

            <!-- password -->
            <VCol cols="12">
              <VTextField
                v-model="form.password"
                label="Password"
                placeholder="············"
                :type="isPasswordVisible ? 'text' : 'password'"
                :append-inner-icon="isPasswordVisible ? 'bx-hide' : 'bx-show'"
                @click:append-inner="isPasswordVisible = !isPasswordVisible"
              />

              <!-- remember me checkbox -->
              <div class="d-flex align-center justify-space-between flex-wrap mt-1 mb-4">
                <VCheckbox
                  v-model="form.remember"
                  label="Remember me"
                />

                <RouterLink
                  class="text-primary ms-2 mb-1"
                  to="javascript:void(0)"
                >
                  Forgot Password?
                </RouterLink>
              </div>

              <!-- login button -->
              <VBtn
                block
                type="submit"
              >
                Login
              </VBtn>
            </VCol>

            <!-- create account -->
            <VCol
              cols="12"
              class="text-center text-base"
            >
              <span>New on our platform?</span>
              <RouterLink
                class="text-primary ms-2"
                to="/register"
              >
                Create an account
              </RouterLink>
            </VCol>

            <VCol
              cols="12"
              class="d-flex align-center"
            >
              <VDivider />
              <span class="mx-4">or</span>
              <VDivider />
            </VCol>

            <!-- auth providers -->
            <VCol
              cols="12"
              class="text-center"
            >
              <AuthProvider />
            </VCol>
          </VRow>
        </VForm>
      </VCardText>
    </VCard>
  </div>
</template>

<style lang="scss">
@use "@core/scss/template/pages/page-auth.scss";
.danger{color:red;padding:20px;}
</style>
```

When i use the $router.push inside login success, the control switches to the catch block of the Promise object and i get the error. If I avoid the push statement i get login success. I want to redirect to dashboard page, when login is success.

My router/index.ts

```
import { createRouter, createWebHistory } from 'vue-router'

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(import.meta.env.BASE_URL),
  routes: [
    { path: '/', redirect: '/login' },

    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('../layouts/default.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: 'dashboard',
          component: () => import('../pages/dashboard.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'account-settings',
          component: () => import('../pages/account-settings.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'typography',
          component: () => import('../pages/typography.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'icons',
          component: () => import('../pages/icons.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'cards',
          component: () => import('../pages/cards.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'tables',
          component: () => import('../pages/tables.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'form-layouts',
          component: () => import('../pages/form-layouts.vue'),
        },
      ],
    },
    {
      path: '/',
      component: () => import('../layouts/blank.vue'),
      children: [
        {
          path: 'login',
          component: () => import('../pages/login.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: 'register',
          component: () => import('../pages/register.vue'),
        },
        {
          path: '/:pathMatch(.*)*',
          component: () => import('../pages/[...all].vue'),
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
})

export default router
```

Please help to find where is the error.

Comment: Did you check the network call ?

Comment: @abhay how to check the network call? All is fine without the push statement

Comment: I don't see where you import & defined router. Maybe add `import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'; const router = useRouter(); router.replace('/dashboard');`

Comment: ```this.$router.push('dashboard');``` maybe, this is how it should write.